# ROBLOX ProximinityPrompt door not opening or closing

Tags: lua, roblox

I am in ROBLOX studio (the newest version) and my code isn't working.

The LocalScript is parented to a part with a ProximityPrompt.

Although there are no errors, nor warnings, it cannot open or close the door.

The code is below this line.

```
door = script.Parent
isOpen = false

function openDoor()
    door.Transparency = 1
    door.CanCollide = false
    isOpen = true
end

function closeDoor()
    door.Transparency = 0
    door.CanCollide = true
    isOpen = false
end

function main()
    if isOpen then
        openDoor() 
    else 
        closeDoor()
    end
end

door.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(main)

closeDoor()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs for LocalScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript) :

> A LocalScript will only run Lua code if it is a descendant of one of the following objects:
>
> - A Player’s Backpack, such as a child of a Tool
> - A Player’s character model
> - A Player’s PlayerGui
> - A Player’s PlayerScripts.
> - The ReplicatedFirst service

So, unless it's important that this code only run on a single client, just swap the code over to a server Script.

Comment: Thank you! That help a lot with this game that I'm working on.